# Iterating multiple collections in MongoDB using the Node.jS driver and comparing results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have two collections in a MongoDB database: "photos" and "albums".

Each document in the albums collection contains an "images" property which contains an array of ids which are a key back to the photos collection.

Using the Node.js driver I need to iterate over the albums collection and remove orphan images, i.e. images which are not in any album.

I can't seem to figure it out... this is the code I've written

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/photosharing', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var images = db.collection('images');
    var albums = db.collection('albums');
    var myArray = [];

    db.albums.count({}, function(err, count) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.dir("start length of albums is " + count);
    });

    images.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if(err) throw err;

        for (var i=1; i<=docs.length; i++) {

            albums.count({"images": i}, function(err, count) {
                if(err) throw err;

                if ( count == 0 ) {
                    images.remove({images.find({ "_id": i })})
                }
            });

        };    
    });

    db.albums.count({}, function(err, count) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.dir("end length of albums is " + count);
    });

    db.close();

  });
```

Comment: What's the error?  It looks like you have some asynchronicity problems in your 'start length'/'end length' portions, but that shouldn't affect whether it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code which does what you need.

But, I will recommend to you try few times before, then try another few, before asking others for help, as it seems that you've tried one way - didn't worked and did not tried other options, while in development there is always many ways of implementing 'same' thing.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/photosharing', function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;

  var images = db.collection('images');
  var albums = db.collection('albums');
  var imageIds = [ ];
  var imageIdKeys = { };

  albums.find({ }).toArray(function(err, data) {
    if (!err) throw err;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      for(var n = 0; n < data[i].images.length; n++) {
        if (!imageIdKeys[data[i].images[n]]) {
          imageIdKeys[data[i].images[n]] = true;
          imageIds.push(data[i].images[n]);
        }
      }
    }

    images.remove({ _id: { $nin: imageIds } }, function(err) {
      if (!err) throw err;

      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

It will collect all ids of images preventing duplicate ID's. This can be also done using aggregations in much better manner, but I've decided to use node.js logic to collect ID's. Then it will remove all documents from `images` collection with ID which is not mentioned in `imageIds` array.

And only after all is done - close database connection.